# Power-analysis and effect size in linear mixed models (post-hoc)

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, effect-size, statistical-power

I'm currently analyzing data using linear mixed models (lme4 package in R) for my master thesis, and my promotor suggested running a post-hoc power analysis to justify that some factors did not end up being significant.

We did an experiment on statistical learning with children and adults. In a recognition task, participants were asked which of the two pseudowords they were presented they already know (from previous exposure) and whether they remembered, it seemed familiar or they were guessing (memory). I used the following code to make my model:

model <- glmer(Accuracy~Group*Memory + (1|Subject), data = recog, family = 'binomial')

So as fixed factors, I have group, memory and their interaction and as random factor I have the intercept of subject.

I looked at the simr-package but had a hard time applying it to my model. When using the powerSim, I keep getting error "Couldn't automatically determine a default fixed effect for this model." I would like to know the power of the overall model (similar as one would for an ANOVA). I also was unsure on what to do with the effect sizes - should I use the observed ones or specify them differently.

An alternative idea was to calculate the power of an anova with the same variables. But then I found myself unsure how to specify the overall effect size (as required by programs like GPower).

Can anyone offer any insight on this or recommend sources? I already took a look at 
Green, P., & MacLeod, C. J. (2016). SIMR: an R package for power analysis of generalized linear mixed models by simulation. Methods in Ecology and Evolution, 7(4), 493-498. 
and
Brysbaert, M., & Stevens, M. (2018). Power analysis and effect size in mixed effects models: A tutorial. Journal of Cognition, 1(1).

but found it difficult to apply to my model because their examples often only use one fixed effect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a quick comment: "Don't calculate post-hoc power using observed estimate of effect size" by Andrew Gelman (2018): http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/power_surgery_3.pdf

Comment: In general, I would prefer confidence intervals to judge whether your results came up non-significant because the effects are really too small to be relevant, or because you have too much uncertainty in your estimates. Power analysis one should conduct _before_ collecting the data. Additionally, p-values in mixed models are controversial, hence any power analysis is actually quite controversial, too.

Comment: @LuckyPal I have used p-values because my promotor recommended it. Could you give me any leads on how to obtain and interpret confidence intervals for mixed models (preferably using lme4/ afex)?

Comment: For confidence intervals in lme4, there is the function 'confint()'. For an extensive discussion of significance testing in mixed models, particularly in lme4, you may read into "Evaluating significance in linear mixed-effects models in R" (Luke, 2017) https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-016-0809-y